# `which conda` doesn't output a path

Tags: anaconda

I think `which conda` should output the path to the binary, but instead I get this:

```
$ which conda
conda () {
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]
    then
        "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA
    else
        \local cmd="$1"
        shift
        case "$cmd" in
            (activate | deactivate) __conda_activate "$cmd" "$@" ;;
            (install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall) CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}" 
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
                \local t1=$?
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}" 
                if [ $t1 = 0 ]
                then
                    __conda_reactivate
                else
                    return $t1
                fi ;;
            (*) CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}" 
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
                \local t1=$?
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}" 
                return $t1 ;;
        esac
    fi
}
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but I would guess that the reason is that you don’t specify an actual objective (what are you trying to accomplish?) or your environment (I guess you are running bash; can you confirm that and tell us the version?), and you don’t seem to have tried to figure it out yourself. Try `type which`, `type conda` and `printf '%s\n' "$CONDA_EXE"`. See [Gerard H. Pille’s answer below](//superuser.com/q/1602014/150988#1602021) and my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/194893/23408#194900 "Why can't I load modules while executing my bash script, but only when sourcing it?").

Answer (score 0):

In your environment, a conda function has been defined. I would try

```
conda install
```

Comment: `conda install <package>` is used to install a package, just `conda install` will throw `CondaValueError: too few arguments, must supply command line package specs or --file`. Also, the conda binary works, so, somehow it is in the PATH.